VS Code Intellisense's response for FastAPI's `response_model`
In the code below, Vs Code suggests that the output should be of type Any instead of UserOut. Did I miss out on some configurations on my Vs Code?
# based on https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel,

class UserIn(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str
    email: EmailStr
    full_name: str|None = None

class UserOut(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    full_name: str | None = None

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/user2", response_model=UserOut)
async def create_user2(user: UserIn) -> Any:
    return user


